# Using ASN.1 to express bit mask

Tags: asn.1

I would like to know if there is a standard way to express a bit mask that is complementing to another data field in ASN.1.

For example, there is a bits field called machine status defined as below

```
Machine_Status::= BIT STRING (SIZE(16)){
                  battery-low(0),
                  temperature-low(1),
                  monitor-plugged-in(2),
                  ....
                  humidity-high(15)
                  }
```

However, there is a complementing bit mask for Machine Status to indicate certain status bit is meaningful (says if the client enables certain status detection)

```
 Machine_Status_Mask::=BIT STRING(SIZE(16)){
                  battery-low-detect-supported(0),
                  temperature-low-detect-supported(1),
                  monitor-plugged-in-detect-supported(2),
                  ....
                  humidity-high-detect-support(15)
                       }
```

My question is, if I want to define a general mask data type so that I don't need to define a new mask type for every possible bit strings, how should I do that? To illustrate this concept, please see the following example,

```
//This is what I want, but I am not sure if there is a better or more legit way to express in ASN.1
Bit_Mask::=BIT STRING(SIZE(16)){
           bit-0-of-target-is-meaningful(0),
           bit-1-of-target-is-meaningful(1),
           bit-1-of-target-is-meaningful(2),
           ....
           bit-15-of-target-is-meaningful(15)
}
```

And I can apply this data type to any other bit string of size(16) to form a buddle, say

```
Machine_Status_Bundle::=SEQUENCE{
    status Machine_Status_Mask,
    mask   Bit_Mask
}

Communication_Status_Bundle::SEQUENCE{
    status Communication_Status_Mask,
    mask   Bit_Mask
}
```

Comment: What you have seems reasonable to me.  What don't you like about it?

Comment: @Kevin just to make sure it is correct expression to communicate what I want.